# Using C# attributes on WCF REST endpoints for authentication/authorisation

Tags: c#, wcf

For particular endpoints on my rest service I need to check a token, rather than doing this in each of those endpoints:

```
IncomingWebRequestContext woc = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest;    
string tok = woc.Headers["tok"];
// validate etc
```

I'd like to put an attribute on the endpoint's method and do something like this:

```
[Restricted]
public Blog Get(string id)
```

And make the endpoint return custom responses, can I get headers and control method return values like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two ways to do this:

- You can use an external tool like [postsharp](/questions/tagged/postsharp) to implement [aspect oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). That means your attribute (plain metadata right now with standard .NET) becomes an Aspect and executes code. This is achieved through a post-compiler that weaves IL code. Cool stuff, but it costs money.
- You write your own [IEndpointBehavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.servicemodel.description.iendpointbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx) to [apply a dispatch behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.servicemodel.description.iendpointbehavior.applydispatchbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx) to your service endpoint, that in turn will add an [IDispatchMessageInspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector(v=vs.110).aspx) that can examine the message (for example for headers) and act accordingly for all messages to your endpoint. It could also check your endpoint actions, whether they have such an attribute set and act only on those that have it.

Comment: You say check your endpoint actions for an attribute, if I do would I have to implement IServiceBehavior so I could look at every request to service and look for das method attribute?

Comment: @el_pup_le Yes, indeed.

Comment: If I implement IEndpointBehavior would I have to add the behavior to every endpoint in the config file? Which would be better considering the inspector is being used for authentication/authorisation?

Comment: If you use the config file and you want every endpoint to have this behavior, you will have to add it there.

Comment: How do I get the method being called from the AfterReceiveRequest in the inspector? Sorry .net is hard to navigate